# Is homoscedasticity met?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I'm fairly new to statistics. Could you help me, please?
I've got the scatterplot of residuals versus predicted value. It seems that the data points aren't scattered around zero with a constant width.
Am I right that homoscedasticity hasn't been met? What should I do? I have 5 independent variables, two of which are categorical. Can I make a prediction in this case? [image]

Comment: What is the model? Regression, ANOVA, something else? How to judge such a plot of residuals can depend on what model is used.

Comment: The apparent heteroscedasticity in the figure implies prediction--which certainly is possible (after all, you have constructed the plot from predicted values!)--will have a level of uncertainty that varies with the predicted value itself.  Would that be a problem for you?

Comment: @BruceET a multiple linear regression model for sales

Answer (score 1):

This looks reasonable to me.  Heterogeneity of variance is only an issue for inference, not prediction.  If you're worried about homogeneity of variance being violated, you could use a sandwhich estimator instead.  In the case where there is no heterogeneity of variance and you use the sandwhich, you lose a bit of power.  Seems like a worth while tradeoff to me.

Comment: Two statements that may seem contradictory: 1. If the scatter is strongly heteroscedastic that will leap out at you. 2. Just eyeballing the graph may not be enough, as it's hard to adjust mentally for variations in frequency across the graph. Consider smoothing (residual$^2)^{1/3}$ -- where squaring first makes all residuals 0 or positive and cube rooting damps outlying values -- as a function of fitted.

Comment: In the example a wedge shape s evident for low values. Sometimes this implies you would be better off with logarithmic scale.

Comment: It appears that the data are bounded below by zero, and this is what is causing the heteroscedasticity. After all, when the data are forced toward a boundary, there is necessarily less variance. (cf, SJ Gould, "Full House".)

Answer (score 0):

Just from Visual inspection, I cannot detect heteroskedasticity. But I advice you to run some statistical tests like White Test

Comment: The heteroscedasticity looks clear to many of us, so your statement to the contrary needs to be backed up by an explanation of what method you are using to detect it.  What features are you examining in your visual inspection to assess heteroscedasticity?